# C Issues with RegEnumKeyExA receiving ERROR_MORE_DATA

Tags: c, registry

after a few years off with C I am trying to find myself into C again. Sorry for the question, it might be easy to some of you.

I am trying to understand why the code below gets a 234 Error Code (ERROR_MORE_DATA) for the return value of RegEnumKeyExA.

```
LONG lRValue;
    DWORD dwIndex = 0;
    DWORD dwKeyNameLength;
    DWORD subKeysCount;
    HKEY hOpenKey;
    TCHAR *keyName = TEXT("Software");

    lRValue = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyName, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hOpenKey);

    if (lRValue == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("<<<< Key opened successfully. >>>>\n");
    } else {
        printf("---- Error detected! ----");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    lRValue = RegQueryInfoKeyA(hOpenKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &subKeysCount, &dwKeyNameLength, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (lRValue == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("<<<< Key queried successfully. >>>>\n");
        printf("KeyNameLength: %i\n", dwKeyNameLength);
        printf("SubKeyCount: %i\n", subKeysCount);
    } else {
        printf("---- Error detected! ----");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    TCHAR lpName[dwKeyNameLength];

    for(int i = 0; i < subKeysCount; i++) {
        int lrValue = RegEnumKeyExA(hOpenKey, dwIndex, lpName, &dwKeyNameLength, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (lrValue != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            printf("Error in: %i\n", lrValue);
        }
        printf("%s\n", lpName);
        dwIndex++;
    }

    printf("%i\n", dwIndex);
    printf("<<<< Job completed! >>>>");
```

I fear it has something to do with the buffer size, but I thought I correctly identified it by doing the RegQueryInfo. The code above is surely not very perofrmant, but this should not be the topic.

Anyone have any idea? :)

Thank you. :)

Comment: Because there aren't 10 subkeys?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are definitely more than 10 subkeys. :)

Comment: In this example usage of the similar [RegEnumKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/enumerating-registry-subkeys) they simply ignore any result unless `if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)`

Comment: Thank you again. I also tried this just for fun - with the result that registry keys are listed more than one time. And t every second key I get this error. I will give you an example output what happens for understanding: ```<<<< Key opened successfully. >>>>
<<<< Key queried successfully. >>>>
KeyNameLength: 39
Adobe
Error in: 234
Adobe
Error in: 234
Adobe
Error in: 234
Adobe
Error in: 234
Adobe
Error in: 234
Adobe
Dell
Error in: 234
Dell
Error in: 234
Dell
Error in: 234
Dell
10
<<<< Job completed! >>>>```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problems are in this line:

```
int lrValue = RegEnumKeyExA(hOpenKey, dwIndex, lpName, &dwKeyNameLength, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Here you are supplying the address of the length as parameter 4 (&dwKeyNameLength). After the first call it read `Adobe` and has afterwards the value 5. So if the next lpName entry is longer (most likely) it will not work.

You also have to take care of the terminating NULL character. Microsoft writes in the documentation:

> > A pointer to a variable that specifies the size of the buffer specified by the lpName parameter, in characters. This size should include the terminating null character. If the function succeeds, the variable pointed to by lpcName contains the number of characters stored in the buffer, not including the terminating null character.

see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumkeyexa

So the max value must be dwKeyNameLength + 1.

So to fix both issues, just set the value of it in the loop to the max value plus 1 for the terminating NULL.

**Miscellaneous**

- KEY_ALL_ACCESS is not necessary, KEY_READ is for enumerating sufficient
- WINAPI calls are available in two variants: with suffix A (single char version) and suffix W (wide char version). Better to use it without suffix and depending on the projects Unicode setting the correct version is chosen automatically.
- a RegCloseKey is missing in your code at the end
- to avoid an signed/unsigned mismatch, one should make the variable `i` of type DWORD

**Complete Example**

Here the code from your question only slightly modified. Note: For the dynamic memory allocation for lpName we need to add 1 for the terminating NULL like mentioned above.

Also take a look at this line:

```
DWORD cchName = dwKeyNameLength + 1;
```

Inside the loop the value is always reset to this buffer size.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void enumerate();

void __cdecl _tmain(void) {
    enumerate();
}

void enumerate()
{
    DWORD lRValue;
    DWORD dwKeyNameLength;
    DWORD subKeysCount;
    HKEY hOpenKey;
    TCHAR* keyName = _T("Software");

    lRValue = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyName, 0, KEY_READ, &hOpenKey);

    if (lRValue == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        _tprintf(_T("<<<< Key opened successfully. >>>>\n"));
    }
    else {
        _tprintf(_T("---- Error detected! ----"));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    lRValue = RegQueryInfoKey(hOpenKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &subKeysCount, &dwKeyNameLength, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (lRValue == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        _tprintf(_T("<<<< Key queried successfully. >>>>\n"));
        _tprintf(_T("KeyNameLength: %i\n"), dwKeyNameLength);
        _tprintf(_T("SubKeyCount: %i\n"), subKeysCount);
    }
    else {
        _tprintf(_T("---- Error detected! ----"));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    TCHAR *lpName = malloc((dwKeyNameLength + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < subKeysCount; i++) {
        DWORD cchName = dwKeyNameLength + 1;
        lRValue = RegEnumKeyEx(hOpenKey, i, lpName, &cchName, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (lRValue != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            _tprintf(_T("Error at index: %d\n"), i);
        } else {
            _tprintf(_T("%s (%d)\n"), lpName, cchName);
        }
    }

    free(lpName);
    RegCloseKey(hOpenKey);

    _tprintf(_T("<<<< Job completed! >>>>"));
}
```